# Match nth instance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array of data in a spreadsheet that I want to automagically pull the first seven instances that start with a specific string to seven independent cells so it can easily be seen what the full cell contents are. I have composed a formula that successfully finds the first occurrence but I can't find a way to extend this to the second, third etc. I have thought of using the previous cell's match as input to the next cell, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.

I have found some examples that use VBA or CSE formulas, but any CSE formulas I have tried don't seem to work. But due to constraints imposed on me I can't use VBA or CSE anyway so I never looked too deeply in to it.

Here is the formula that matches the first instance:

```
=INDEX($A$13:$A$5000,MATCH("start*",$A$13:$A$5000,0))
```

This is in Cell A4; I would like A5:A11 to match the next six instances.

Is this possible in a vanilla formula?

Comment: Why can't you use CSE? What version of Excel are you using? What does "vanilla formula" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an "array" function (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) but I personally do not like using those.

My suggestion would be the following instead:

A4 `=INDEX($A$13:$A$5000,MATCH("start*",$A$13:$A$5000,0))`

B4 `=MATCH("start*",$A$13:$A$5000,0)`

A5 `=INDEX(OFFSET($A$13:$A$5000,B4,0),MATCH("start*",OFFSET($A$13:$A$5000,B4,0),0))`

And copy this down to A11

B5 `=MATCH("start*",OFFSET($A$13:$A$5000,B4,0),0)+B4`

And copy this down to B11

Basically this "pushes" the search area down an amount equal to the sum of the previous matches, and then finds the next match.

Comment: I'm not able to do a separate helper column, however I just put the helper cells at the bottom of the same row. I was also able to simplify the output cells due to your creating a reference list with =INDEX($A$13:$A$5000,A6000) in A13 and =INDEX($A$13:$A$5000,A6001) in A14 etc. A perfect score for what I asked for!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Helper column.  In **B13** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A13,5)="start",1+MAX($B$1:B12),"")
```

and copy down.  Then in **A4** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$13:$A$5000,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$B$13:$B$5000,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on the other answers, still using a helper column starting in B4 and pulled down to get the match position in a$13:a$5000:-

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("BR*",INDEX(A$13:A$5000,B3+1):A$5000,0)+B3,"")
```

(assuming B3 is empty).

Then to get the corresponding match in A4 and pulled down:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$13:A$5000,B4),"")
```

(my test data uses strings starting with BR).

[image]