# Copying data that matches a cell to first empty cell

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to complete this without vb/macros but not sure if a formula can do this.

Sheet1!$A$1 = Company 
Sheet2!$A:$A = List of multiple companies 
Sheet2!$B:$B = Employees attached to that company 
Sheet1!$A$3:$A = Blank spots

I need a formula in Sheet1!$A$3 That cross checks Sheet1!$A$1 with Sheet2!$A:$A and pulls all the Employees attached to the company that matches Sheet1!$A$1 to the blank spots Sheet1!$A$3:$A

Below pulls the first matching company on the list but I can't figure out how to make it pull the ones after.
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet2!$B:$B,0))

This is an idea of what it should look like when working.

[image: Company / Employees]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There was a similar question earlier today at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299275/match-nth-instance/33301063#33301063).  Although this can be done with an array formula, the link points to two options that do not use arrays, but do require a secondary column to store values.

Comment: What is attached to that company? in sheet2 B?

Comment: Sheet!2 contains Employees and their companies. I want to have a header of Company X / Employees on Sheet1! and it auto fill the fist empty spot/s with the employees under that company. 

Thanks for the link. I will check it out